# Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... stuck Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When I run `flutter build appbundle` stuck the terminal on `Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...`  .
Can anyone help me?
Flutter don‘t create the Release folder.
I can't find anything on other forums.

Comment: I change from debug zu release and the other things in the build.gradle file but the problem is the same.